# What is the difference between type, value_type and element_type, and when to use each?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written a template class that should expose its template parameter, but I am unsure of the appropriate naming.

I have found three different names for essentially the same thing (as far as I can tell):

- containers, e.g., `std::vector` use `value_type`
- smart pointers, e.g., `std::unique_ptr` use `element_type`
- `std::reference_wrapper` uses just `type`

What is the idea behind these different names? What standard algorithms or trait classes depend on which name? Which name should I use for my class (something in between a smart pointer and reference wrapper)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`value_type` is a member type of containers (and iterators and such). It provides the type of an object, usually a complete object, which you can create or observe. There is no casting between `value_type`-covariant templates.

`element_type` is a member type of smart pointers. It provides the type of an observed object. Often smart pointers manage complete objects, but they can also be cast to base subobjects.

`type` is a member type of metafunctions. Usually it doesn't describe any particular object.

Comment: The difference in casting of `value_type` containers and `element_type` pointers is definitely interesting. I don't quite follow your reasoning for the name `type` though. What do you mean by "it doesn't describe any particular object"?

Comment: @zennehoy Metafunctions such as the ones in `<type_traits>` have no nonstatic members. They aren't concerned with actual objects, but only types.

Comment: Oh, you were referring to trait classes. I was thinking exclusively about classes that contain or reference some value. What about `std::reference_wrapper`, why does it use `type` rather than `element_type`?

Comment: @zennehoy Perhaps `reference_wrapper::type` slipped through the cracks. It's more like a proxy than a smart pointer. It's of similar Boost vintage but from different authors. Reflecting a template parameter as a member is common, but calling that member `type` is not. It seems to have been added as an afterthought between Boost 1.25 and 1.27, to help `boost::function` to process it.

Answer (score 8):

`value_type` is a part of a big family of things to define when you define containers:

```
typedef T value_type;
typedef T& reference;
typedef const T& const_reference;
typedef long size_type;
typedef size_type difference_type;
```

These, in addition to iterators `typedef`s, are all used by STL algorithms to deal with your container in an agnostic way, without knowing the type of your container. These are the reason why the same algorithm works on `std::vector`, `std::deque` and all other STL containers.

On the other hand, `std::unique_ptr` and `std::reference_wrapper` have their typedefs for completeness and to make it also possible to the developer to deduce types. For example, consider the situation:

```
typedef std::vectory<double> MyGreatArray;
//Do stuff with MyGreatArray
//What is the type inside MyGreatArray? I want to assign a single element
MyGreatArray::value_type one_element; //now one_element is a double!
MyGreatArray::iterator MyGreatArrayIt; //now this is an iterator vector<double>
one_element = 1.0;
MyGreatArrayIt = MyGreatArray.begin();
```

(PS: Of course you can use `auto`, but this is the case even before C++11)

So you see, you will always have a reference to the type inside the container. It doesn't matter whether it's an STL container or `std::unique_ptr`, it's just good practice to have a reference of your template type inside your template class, no matter what it's. Since STL and the C++ standard aims toward generality, you'll always find a reference of your template types inside the classes. This will make it easier for everything you do to be independent of the types you put in your templates.

EDIT:

"Why they have different names?" A: Simply to avoid ambiguity. Consider an algorithm that should take a container and requires only a `value_type`. When the names are different, you add extra protection against catastrophic run-time errors. Remember that everything is becoming type-agnostic. The last thing we want is another source of errors by having everything called `value_type`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid you misinterpreted the question. I completely understand why such typedefs exist. What I want to know is why the typedefs have different names, and what the concept behind those different names is.

Comment: @zennehoy Different names are there just to avoid ambiguity. It's not a good idea to call everything `value_type`. Check the updated answer.

Comment: _"Remember that everything is becoming type-agnostic"_ The sentences around this one are why I think this trend is dangerous :( When you have to come up with "workarounds" for the fact that you deliberately evaded your type system, something's surely wrong!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Agreed. Though there are pros and cons to everything :)

Comment: Templates are the C++-way of duck typeing (if it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, then for all intents and purposes it is a duck). Using different names should only be done if there are no common use cases where either type could make sense. Given the different names, it is for example not possible to use `value_type` or `element_type` in a function that just expects something dereferencable, allowing both smart pointers or iterators.

Comment: @zennehoy I think you answered your own question ;)

Comment: How so? I want to write a function that would work fine for both smart pointers and iterators, but can't use `value_type` because that would limit my function to iterators.

Comment: @zennehoy Because this behavior is dangerous and hence wrong. There's nothing common between smart pointers and STL containers, unless you make there something common between them. The idea behind smart pointers is type safety, and you want to kill that by dealing with it as a C-pointer. Don't you see the design flaw there? In very basic, academic form, if every bird can fly, then not everything that flies is a bird. Your doing exactly that when you try to put STL containers and smart pointers as "dereferenceables". The C++ standard doesn't support that model, and hence protects you from it.

Comment: Simple example: `template <typename T> T::value_type const &dereference(T const &ptr) { return *ptr; }` Why should that be limited to iterators? Without the `value_type`, it would work just as well for smart pointers. Yes that example could/should be done with a traits class, but I am sure there are similar cases only hindered by the inconsistent naming.

Comment: @zennehoy Are you familiar with the mathematical disproving method called "counter-example"? it says roughly: 1 failed example suffices to disprove a model, and a 100 successful examples don't prove a model. You providing 1 working example doesn't prove your model is correct for every case. E.g., `1.5+2.5=4`, it doesn't mean that the sum of any two numbers is an integer. You can't request a rule to be made based on one example, when we talk about the general case. I can give you many examples where this is unsafe, and that suffices to be good evidence that type-ducking that way is wrong.

Comment: @zennehoy and btw, C++ doesn't prevent you from anything. You're free to inherit from `std::unique_ptr` and add `value_type`. Then it's your responsibility. ;)

Comment: The same goes the other way, depending on where you start from :) To help me better understand your view of things, could you provide a simple example where the difference in name protects you from something that the actual usage does not?

Comment: @zennehoy No. It's not the same the other way. You're asking for *more*, and more requires more proof. You should provide a model where you should that it's never unsafe. I think you should do that in another question. If you like that model, then simply implement it in your design and use it. I'm sorry I can't provide examples now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's more "different uses use deliberately different names"