# Why is there element_type in std::span and value_type of std::span is remove_cv_t<element_type> in C++?

Tags: c++

In other containers, there is only a `value_type`, which is exactly the template parameter.

But why `value_type` of `std::span` is the type of remove_cv_t, and defined another type named `element_type`, which as far as I know is only used in `unique_ptr,shared_ptr`.

What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063845/what-is-the-difference-between-type-value-type-and-element-type-and-when-to-us

Comment: A span has range semantics, so it has `value_type` (like other ranges in `std`), and it has pointer semantics, so it has `element_type`.

Comment: @Caleth But why should `value_type` be cv-removed?

Comment: The original proposal [P0122R7](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0122r7.pdf) used `value_type` for constructing a `span` from `array<value_type, N>`. Such that we could construct `span<const int>` from `array<int,N>`. But this constructor was replaced by a templated more-generic constructor for `array<T,N>` then: http://eel.is/c++draft/views.span#span.cons-11. Relevant LWG: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3255.

Comment: This is such an arbitrary and annoying inconsistency to be honest. For literally all other containers you expect `value_type` to be the exact element type of the container (`vector<value_type>`, `array<value_type, size>` etc. But all of a sudden `span` comes along and changes this, rendering any generic code depending on the (previous) fact useless...

Comment: FWIW I use this trait to reliably get the `value_type` for any range:
`
template<typename range_t>
using range_value_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<range_t&>()))>;
`

Comment: @helmesjo If anything, I think containers should be stripping `const` from their `value_type` instead. It's so rare to use `const` element types that probably nobody noticed. (and GCC outright rejects `vector<const T>`, but does allow `array<const T>`) Compare this with `const_iterator`s of containers, which have non-const `value_type`. What do you use `value_type` for? Perhaps you can/should use `pounter` or `reference`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, for me I just want something globally consistent to rely on (across all container types). 
Specifically in my current scenario I use any (sequence) container as byte storage, so at one point I need to cast to either `std::byte*` or `const std::byte*` depending on (previously) `value_type`. But thanks for the suggestions and yes, eg. `reference` type appears to be consistent between `std::span` and others, it's just specifically `value_type` that diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Recently noticed this myself so can't add any explanation but FWIW, as a workaround, I use this trait to reliably get the `value_type` for any range:

```cpp
template<typename range_t>
using range_value_t = 
  std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<range_t&>()))>;
```