What is the idiomatic way to have a member function of a template class with a declaration valid only if the template argument satisfies some concept?
The C++20 Concepts language feature allows one to constrain member functions of template classes.  However, these constraints apply only to the body of the member functions, and not the declaration - the declaration still needs to be valid.
I'm facing a situation where the declaration may not be semantically valid, but I would like to avoid a compilation error as long as the user does not try to call that member function.
For example:
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct A {
    // how to rewrite this declaration so that it works?
    typename T::value_type f(typename T::value_type x) requires std::integral<typename T::value_type> {
        return x * 10;
    }
};

int main(){
    A<std::vector<int>> a; // compiles
    A<int> b; // does not compile, but we want this to compile as long as the user doesn't call `b.f`
    struct B { using value_type = void; };
    A<B> c; // does not compile, but we want this to compile as long as the user doesn't call `c.f`
    
}

The compilation error is:
<source>: In instantiation of 'struct A<int>':
<source>:12:12:   required from here
   12 |     A<int> b; // does not compile
      |            ^
<source>:5:28: error: 'int' is not a class, struct, or union type
    5 |     typename T::value_type f(typename T::value_type x) requires std::integral<typename T::value_type> {
      |                            ^
<source>: In instantiation of 'struct A<main()::B>':
<source>:14:10:   required from here
   14 |     A<B> c; // does not compile
      |          ^
<source>:5:28: error: invalid parameter type 'main()::B::value_type' {aka 'void'}
    5 |     typename T::value_type f(typename T::value_type x) requires std::integral<typename T::value_type> {
      |                            ^
<source>:5:28: error: in declaration 'typename T::value_type A<T>::f(typename T::value_type) requires  integral<typename T::value_type>'

What is the idiomatic way to rewrite the declaration of the member function f so that the code compiles?

I suspect that value_type is only applicable to STL containers? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063845/what-is-the-difference-between-type-value-type-and-element-type-and-when-to-us

Possibly, but that's not the point of this question; it could be any dependent type.

I'm not sure about idiomatic, but there is a trick you can employ—have an identical template argument that doesn't get substituted until later:
template<std::same_as<T> U = T>
requires std::integral<typename T::value_type> 
typename U::value_type f(typename U::value_type x) {
    return x * 10;
}

The expectation is that this template argument would never be provided explicitly. It's meant to always be such that U is the same type as T, but since it appears possible to change U, substitution won't happen at T time, so the hard errors are avoided.
One could argue using T vs. U in the requires, but it shouldn't make a difference in behaviour when f is used correctly and they're the same type. requires will handle substitution failures by failing the requirement.

One can also add requires std::same_as<T,U> just in case.

@n.m.couldbeanAI, Fair point, that would succinctly prevent misuse.

Or better template <std::same_as<T> U = T>.

You can also write template<typename..., typename U = T> to prevent the user from ever providing U explicitly, though the type constraint seems more elegant here.

That's the succinct way, and pretty much readable. I can't think of any shorter method. There would be a tone of unreadable boilerplate otherwise.

@Red.Wave, The other answer is especially good when there are multiple functions with the same requirements.

@chris in that case you can define a template variable to simplify the requires expression and continue the same pattern as above. The only bothersome part is extra typename spam. The other solution creates a boiler plate and is less readable - due to encapsulation in base.

Another way is to place specific code in a base class with specialization:
template <typename T>
struct A_Base {};

template <typename T>
requires std::integral<typename T::value_type>
struct A_Base<T> {
    T::value_type f(T::value_type x) { return x * 10; }
};

template <typename T>
struct A : A_Base<T>
{
};

Demo

This idiom is also called "mixin"; see What are Mixins (as a concept)
